# using google maps in the java app

Tags: java, google-maps, jakarta-ee

I want to use google maps in my java web app. What i want is when a user visits a particular page his location be showed in the map with its ip address as the input. Is it possible ?

Also the map should be able to locate the position the user entered in the text-field. How can i do that ?

I even downloaded http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list the jar files,samples from the link but they don't work as some of the packages are missing like `com.google.gdata.util` .

Answer (score 1):

I have used Google maps more on the Javascript side.

And i always find [Google Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/) to be the best tutor in helping out.

Check it out.

Comment: In the left pane chose map section. In the right pane you can see the code. And to the top of it you have options to View the raw html which you can directly use, or you can view the docs to learn it and use it better.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use JavaScript to use the Google Maps API. Here's a sample of using HTML5 geolocation to find someone's location: http://html5demos.com/geo

For user input, you might check out using the Google Maps API Places Library which has an autocomplete function: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete